# Specify my date PHP

Tags: php

I have attribut date_input in my database

```
etat_input : 2016-06-06
```

I would convert my date on format:

```
since :  06 june 2016
```

I try with :

```
<?php  echo $var['etat_input'];?>
```

but no result.

Comment: read about date function - http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: You may want to read this and try before this question is put to hold: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First convert `date_input` to timestamp:

```
$timestamp = strtotime($var['etat_input']);
```

Now feed that `$timestamp` to `date` with proper format:

```
date('d M Y', $timestamp);
```

[PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fbf97020d88d22bef4c9fc44a691b0af5b23b956) example